# PowerShell Core proxy issues

Tags: windows, proxy, windows-10, http-proxy, powershell-core

I just wanted to share this with you all. If I knew what to ask for, I would have created a ticket up front. But what I found online was partly misleading.
It was a combination of searching and trying, until I finally found the solution.

This issues was related to running PowerShell Core on a corporate machine, initially setup for Proxy use.

**Problem description**

After fresh installation of PowerShell Core, Install-Module where unable to resolve package source and Invoke-WebRequest "any-external-url" reported "No such host". This is all under Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to my issue**

I had to do all of this to bypass the proxy.

1. First was to unset the Environment Variable for the proxy. (Maybe you also need to do this for HTTP_PROXY environment variable)

`Set-Item -Path Env:HTTPS_PROXY -Value ""`

2. Reset proxy for HttpClient

`[System.Net.Http.HttpClient]::DefaultProxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy($null)`

3. Reset proxy for HttpWebRequest

`[System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy($null)`

I ended up adding them to the PowerShell 7 profile.

Hope it save some time for at least one more soul. :)